# Efficient way to get all the field (column) values in an array from SharePoint List

Tags: list, column, splist, spfield

I have to get all the field (column) values in an array from a SharePoint list. Right now I am looping through all the items in the list and creating an array. But it is very inefficient if I have large number of items.

What would be the most efficient way to get all the field (column) values in an array from SharePoint List?

Update 1: The array values are further used in the code and are not displayed to end user.

Comment: Why u r not using DatTable?

Comment: you looking for Jquery or CSOM/ SSOM ?

Comment: @Gaurravs: SSOM. But if its possible in CSOM then it should be available in SSOM, right?

Comment: @DikeshGandhi: `SPList.GetDataTable()` fetches me the data table. But then I cannot find any method in the DataTable Class that will return the column values in array. Or am I missing something here? Please elaborate what are you referring to.

Comment: @Naveen: Where will you use array? or What operations you wants to do after getting data in array?

Comment: @DikeshGandhi: The array will be looped through and there's another set of logic that is applied on each value with another list to get some records. Please note, I require an array which would then be used ahead in my code. So a DataTable would not be an option for me. I do not need to display array values to user.

Comment: I guess use of generic list can also suffice your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Even I will suggest using DataTable than array

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["List_Name"];
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;

//DataTable oDataTable = collListItems.GetDataTable();

DataGrid1.DataSource = collListItems.GetDataTable();
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

you can either use grid or the commented line if want in datatable format for further functionality.

Or

You can get list items collection in a generic list.

```
List<SPListItem> listItems = list.GetItems(query).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList();
```